# ssh "Connection timed out" after first reboot of a Raspberry Pi

Tags: networking, server, 20.04, raspberrypi, cloud-init

I am trying to setup an Ubuntu 20.04 Server on a Raspberry Pi 4+ (RPi).  Everything works and I can ssh in without a problem the first time the server starts up, both using Ethernet and WiFi.  However, if I reboot the RPi, I get a: `ssh: connect to host 10.0.0.16 port 22: Connection timed out` message.  I have tried booting the RPi without changing any other settings other than adding the WiFi information.  Here is my `network-config` file:

```
version: 2
ethernets:
  eth0:
    # Rename the built-in ethernet device to "eth0"
    match:
      driver: bcmgenet smsc95xx lan78xx
    set-name: eth0
    dhcp4: true
    optional: true
wifis:
  wlan0:
    dhcp4: true
    optional: true
    access-points:
      "<router-name>":
        password: "<router-password>"
```

I can use `arp –na | grep –i ...` on the RPi (when not remote) and see my laptop's IP and `arp -a | findstr ...`  on my Windows machine to see my RPi IP.

I haven't seen any good answers to this question elsewhere.  My thinking is that the cloud-init first boot information works for the first startup but then does not work for subsequent restarts.  The weird thing is, I am still able to use the internet when physically login on to the RPi (run `apt install` to install net-tools for example) even using WiFi so some setting must still load from cloud-init.  Could ssh become disabled after first boot?  Not sure how to fix this, even if this is the case.

Has anyone else had this problem, and if so, have you found a workaround?

Thanks!